Safari open.window has no effect with a delay bigger than 300ms
I want to open a new blank page in Safari after a while when a button click event is fired.
$( "#btn" ).on( "click", function() {
   setTimeout(() => {
      window.open("http://google.com", "_blank");
   }, 300);
} );

In this case it does not work having a delay bigger than at around 300ms.
I would like to set a bigger delay, like 5 seconds but it seems Safari blocks it.
Does anyone now a workaround on this?

This limitation is almost certainly to prevent popup ads; window.open calls can only be triggered by direct user action like a click.
